Generalizing Hartshorne I.6 to non-algebraically closed fields.
Let $L/K$ be a finitely-generated field extension of transcendence degree 1, where $K$ is not necessarily algebraically closed. By Stacks Project Theorem 0BY1 , there is a regular projective curve $C$ whose function field is $L$. The construction of $C$ is described in Hartshorne I.6 in the case where $K$ is algebraically closed, but what if it isn't?
My attempt is: A point of $C$ is a discrete valuation $v : L^* \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $v(x) = 0$ for $x \in K$, along with a generic point $\eta$. The topology is the intersection of the cofinite topology and the particular point topology on $\eta$. If $U$ is open, then $O_C(U)$ is defined as $\{x \in L : v(x) \geq 0$ for all $v \in U \}$.
I want to prove that $C$ is a scheme, then prove its a regular projective curve. I tried to follow chapter I.6 in Hartshorne, but lemma 6.5, which proves that for $x \in L$, $\{v \in C \  \{\eta\} : v(x) \geq 0\}$ is finite, uses an assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed that I don't know how to get around.

This is actually not so bad to work around. Here's the relevant passage where algebraic closedness is used, noting that I'm switching back to Hartshorne's notation where our extension is $k\subset K$:

If $R$ is a valuation ring, then $x\notin R$ if and only if $1/x\in\mathfrak{m}_R$. So letting $y=1/x$, we have to show that if $y\in K$, $y\neq 0$, then $\{R\in C_K\mid y\in\mathfrak{m}_R\}$ is a finite set. If $y\in k$, there are no such $R$, so let us assume $y\notin k$.
We consider the subring $k[y]$ of $K$ generated by $y$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, $y$ is transcendental over $k$, hence $k[y]$ is a polynomial ring. Furthermore, since $K$ is finitely generated and of transcendence degree 1 over $k$, $K$ is a finite field extension of $k(y)$. Now let $B$ be the integral closure of $k[y]$ in $K$. Then by (6.3A), $B$ is a Dedekind domain, and it is also a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

Hartshorne deals with two cases: $y\in k$ and $y$ transcendental over $k$. We can also deal with two cases, but they'll be slightly different: $y$ algebraic over $k$ and $y$ transcendental over $k$.
If $y\neq0$ is algebraic over $k$, then I claim it cannot be in any maximal ideal of a valuation ring with $v(k)=0$: supposing $y$ has minimal polynomial $y^n+c_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1y+c_0$ for $c_i\in k$, then we have that $c_0\neq 0$ and $-c_0=y^n+c_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1y\in\mathfrak{m}$, contradicting the fact that the maximal ideal of a local ring is precisely the non-units. So in fact $\{R\in C_K\mid y\in\mathfrak{m}_R\}$ is empty in this case.
If $y$ is transcendental over $k$, then we can just use the same proof from Hartshorne: everything else works exactly the same way.
